# Constrains look different on my iPhone 5S

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

This is my first post. I just started coding. I want to make my first simple app. I own an iPhone 5S and when I add constrains in compact width / compact width & regular height(in XCode), it shows it right on the iPhone 6S plus simulator. When I try it on my iPhone it just looks weird. I know the sizes of the iPhones are different, but how can I correct this? Now, if I code in compact width / compact width & regular height, it feels like I am coding for an iPhone 6...

I hope someone can help me.

Here is the Storyboard:
[image]

Comment: Please show us your storyboard and/or code.

Comment: http://nl.tinypic.com/r/2u3xv0k/9

Comment: LOL; my company firewall blocks tinypic.com as a possible porn site. Sorry!

Comment: lol really? try this:

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/fi5n143m5/

Comment: Holy shit, nope. This firewall is ridiculous. I'll try to access it by other means.

Comment: Ok. I will wait :)

Comment: Please use imgur for stackoverflow images.

Answer (score 0):

I use compact/regular size classes for portrait, and any/compact for landscape, for those two phones you mention (actually, for all of the phones).

And, (squinting at your constraints in the tiny pic), it looks to me like the constraints are "wrong" (not optimal, at least). You've got the button pinned 550 down and 280 across from the edges, which won't look right for smaller devices.

Try aligning the button to horiz and vertical centers, and it will look right everywhere.

Or pin ONE of the edges of the button, and ONE of the top/bottom edges of the button, to the layout margins on one corner. Then it will look right on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the trailing and bottom constraints, as @Kevin suggests, set both of their `constant`s to `0` (or whatever's reasonable), and make them *greater than or equal*, not equal.

Answer (score 0):

For the constraints to appear fine for different screen sizes, one possible way is to add the required constraints to your button or label or any other component and have a preview look at it in the assistant editor section.(Click on assistant editor and in the split screen that comes up, find the Automatic section and within it the preview option)This helps to view the layout of your app for different screen sizes. This helps to manage your auto layout issues by a good extent.